# Count the number of Monday's that fall on the 13th within a given year, if January 1 is input C++

Tags: c++

> Count the number of Mondays that fall on the 13th within a given year if January 1 is input (there is no leap year consideration) C++.

I have already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169947/how-can-i-find-how-many-times-friday-the-13th-appears-in-a-year) Q&A on StackOverflow, but it seems too complicated to be my homework problem. I am just a freshman with a math major and a beginner in C++. Therefore, I was wondering if there is far easier and elementary ways to solve this problem?

Well, I got stuck right after writing the following little code...

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
enum Month = {Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec};
enum week_day = {Mon, Tue, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun};
int jan1;
cin>>jan1
}
```

Because I cannot determine what is the best way to count the asked Mondays and how to write it in code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Jan 1 always start on a Monday?  Is there a leap year consideration?

Comment: Jan 1 is input by the user. No there is no leap year consideration

Comment: never include anything from /bits/

Comment: if you had to do it with a pen and paper what would you do?

Comment: @pm100 why not to include from <bits/stdc++.h> ?

Comment: cos /bits/ things are implementation internals. You should never need them unless you are doing very advanced things.

Answer (score 1):

I won't do your homework for you, but here's some code to get you started:

```
int monthdays[] = [0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
int day = 1;
int month = 1;
int week_day = 0;  // monday is 0, tuesday is 1, ...  you initialize this based on user input

int monday13count = 0;

while (month <= 12)
{
    // your code goes here
    // evaluate if this is "monday the 13th" => increment monday13count
    // increment day and week_day.
    // adjust for end of month condition
}
```